# r: select(everything()) not working with broom::augment for modeling results

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am looking to create a clean dataframe with reodered columns out of a linear model results `lm`, my eventual aim is to write the dataframe to excel to chart and audit model residuals. First, the sample data:

```
df1 <- cbind.data.frame(dt = seq.Date(as.Date('2019-01-01'),
                                      as.Date('2019-01-10'),
                                      by = 'day' ),
                        depVar = rnorm(10,2,1),
                        indepVar1 = rnorm(10,4,3),
                        indepVar2 = rnorm(10,7,2)
        )
```

Now run the model:

```
modRes <- lm(depVar~ indepVar1, data=df1)

avf1 <- broom::augment(modRes)

library(dplyr)

avf1 <- avf1 %>% 
    # drop what we don't need
    select(-c(.se.fit, .hat, .sigma, .cooksd, .std.resid)) %>% 
    cbind(df1)
```

The above runs well, but i want to add another pipe `%>%` with `select(dt, everything())` so I can reorder the columns. The below returns an error:

```
avf1 <- avf1 %>% 
  select(-c(.se.fit, .hat, .sigma, .cooksd, .std.resid)) %>% # drop what we don't need
  cbind(df1) %>% 
  select(dt, everything())

Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: because once you `cbind(df1)` you have multiple columns names 'depVar' and 'indepVar1'. Use `dplyr::bind_cols()` instead to automatically add "uniquifying" suffixes and solve the problem

Comment: @Nate, thank you. Now that I'm looking at it, how can I programmatically exclude the duplicate columns from `df1` when running `cbind` or `bind_cols`?

Comment: use `augment(modRes) %>%  select(-c(.se.fit, .hat, .sigma, .cooksd, std.resid)) %>% merge(df1, .)` to prevent duplicate columns (and get your desired column ordering). `merge()` implements the idea of [SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead of the bolting/binding objects together by axis (agnostic of contetns) that `cbind/rbind` do.

Answer (score -1):

```
avf1 <- modRes %>%
  augment() %>% 
  select(-c(.se.fit, .hat, .sigma, .cooksd, .std.resid)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df1) %>% 
  select(dt, everything())
```